# Which one to use: super() or self.function() with function defined in the parent class

Tags: python, class, inheritance, super

Let's consider the following dummy example:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a
        self.backup_a = a
        
    def reset_a(self):
        self.a = self.backup_a
        print ('Stop touching my stuff!')
        
class B(A):
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        super().__init__(a)
        self.b = b
        
var = A(2)
var.reset_a()

var = B(2, 4)
var.f()
```

To add a method to `B` which uses the method `reset_a` from `A`, boh syntax with `super().` or `self.` works. Which one is more correct and why?

```
class B(A):
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        super().__init__(a)
        self.b = b
        
    def f(self):
        self.reset_a()
```

OR

```
class B(A):
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        super().__init__(a)
        self.b = b
        
    def f(self):
        super().reset_a()
```

Comment: it depends, if you are calling a function that you have overrided in new class, you use `super()`, if the function is not overrided, you use `self`

Comment: @xcodz-dot That was my assumption too. Thanks. And yes.. typo..

Comment: The class *inherits* all methods and attributes of its super class(es). You only need `super()` if you explicitly need to call the parent's version of the method, like you do in `__init__`, since that would otherwise result in an endless recursion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Inheritance automatically makes all methods ("functions") of the parent available to the child. However, if the child re-implements a method, this hides the parent method for the child.

- Use `self.method` to access a method *regardless* whether it was defined in the child or parent.
- Use `super().method` to *explicitly skip* the method defined by the child, and access the parent method instead.

In general, a method should use `self.method` to access *other* methods but `super().method` to access *its own* parent definition.

This is because in deep inheritance, a method cannot rely on whether/how another method has been overriden – only that [methods of well-behaved child classes are indistinguishable from methods of the parent class](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle). A method can only reliably know that it does itself override *its own parent* method.